# Excel Add-In Creation

Tags: matlab, excel-addins, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to export a Matlab function as an Excel Add-In with the Matlab Compiler, as explained on the Mathworks website (http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlabxl/).

Unfortunatly I still have this error message: does someone see what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you don't have write permissions for the location in which you're trying to save the project.

Perhaps you could try to save it somewhere else, that you definitely do have permissions for, and see if you still get the error.